# Bring up the media uploader on click

Tags: uploads, media-library, theme-options

In my theme's options page. I want to have a textfield where a user can enter a http path to an image.

and

have a button beside it which brings up the media uploader (library) where a user can upload an image and insert its path directly into the text field.

Any ideas on how I can do this ?

Comment: Please provide more details on what have you tried and any code already developed. Providing what you _need_ alone is usually considered _fork-for-me-for-free_ kind of request and is [not in scope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

Go here ... it's not quite ready for prime time but will get you started:

http://www.webmaster-source.com/2013/02/06/using-the-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/#comment-37213

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. If something happens to that link the answer becomes useless. Please try to make your answer here stand alone.